# ElementaryOS compatible with my system?

Tags: system-installation, system

I have a i7 7700k
GTX 980 Gigabyte 
Asus z170i pro gaming 
16 GB DDR4 G.Skill Ram

Will my parts be compatible ? I know some Linux flavours dont offer support for new pc parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.linux.com/news/my-hardware-linux-compatible-find-out-here

It looks as if Nvida supports GTX 980 on linux: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/77844/en-us

I found someone citing wifi issues with the onboard 22 months ago, hopefully, they have patched it by now:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311298

same time frame, citing the same issue plus audio chip complications: 
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212999

Some more digging (Google "linux + chip in question") or the resources in the first link, may complete the rest of your question. I know the people behind linux are constantly working to make it as robust as possible, it is likely this has been patched since these posts almost 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Using ElementaryOS is sure to work with your setup. I have a I5-7500 which uses the same chipset as the I7-7700K, GTX 1060 Asrock something something that again uses same chipset as the Z170i which is the z170 chipset. Talking about ddr4 ram, it doesn't really matter which company you chose, DDR4 is more or less the same no matter what company you buy from.

To install the latest Nvidia driver do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-387
```

after that reboot and it should work, if it doesn't work and you get a black screen if you try to login, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> at the login screen, and write 
apt purge Nvidia

it will remove the driver and take you back to the original noveau linux driver.